# how I can change the upload path from laravel ntervention image

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want change the path upload from laravel 5.4 intervention image, now the images upload to (public) folder, I want change it.

Comment: Intervention image does not upload images... typically you would make an image from the temp $_FILES  and then save it where you want...

Comment: When you save the image instead of save it like `$image = Image::make('public/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);` you could do something like `$image = Image::make('public/the_path_you_want/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);`